# getting a NULL pointer exception when trying to use Spark IDF.fit()

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

trying to run this [example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/ml-features.html#tf-idf-hashingtf-and-idf) in Spark documentation. Getting the error below. Get the same error using the Java version of the example as well. The exact line where I get the error is:

```
idfModel = idf.fit(featurizedData)


Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1142.fit.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 7 in stage 256.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 7.0 in stage 256.0 (TID 3308, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The data i'm using is obtained by reading a Json file which has few thousand records. In Java i'm reading the file as follows:

```
DataFrame myData = sqlContext.read().json("myJsonFile.json");
```

the rest of the code is exactly the same as in the example linked above. featurizedData is a valid DataFrame, I printed it's schema and the first element and everything looks as expected. I have no idea why I'm getting a null pointer exception.

Comment: Any workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have `nan` as the text field for some columns.

Since the question is tagged with `PySpark`, use

`data_nan_imputed = data.fillna("unknown", subset=["text_col1", .., "text_coln"])`

This is a good practice if you have a number of text_cols that you want to combine them to make a single text_col. Otherwise, you can also use

`data_nan_dropped = data.dropna()`

to get rid of the `nan` columns and then fit this dataset. Hopefully, it will work.

For `scala` or `java` use similar `nan` filling statements.